# How do I set up an AppleScript to open a new iTerm2 tab and change the directory?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, iterm

In OS X, how do I set up an AppleScript to

- open a new iTerm2 tab
- change to a directory
- clear the console
- echo the current directory

I had something like this before for regular Terminal, but I can't even find the scripting guide for iTerm2.

Comment: Go to [their website](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home), click "[Documentation](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/documentation)", then click "[Scripting](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/documentation/scripting)". Or what do you mean by "scripting guide"?

Comment: If your trying this with iTerm2, the solution is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692346/new-tab-in-iterm2#_=_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following does almost what you asked for, but it opens a new window.

```
tell application "iTerm"
    set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
    tell current session of newWindow
        write text "cd ~/Desktop; clear; pwd"
    end tell
end tell
```

(This was based on the new iTerm documentation and the [below answer](https://superuser.com/a/1554513/48078), which you should upvote!)

Comment: write text adds the return/newline on its own?

Comment: Apparently, it does! I tried everything before posting. `exec command` does *something*, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. I also found the comments at the bottom of this page to be helpful in writing a "cd to" script: http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/AppleScript

Comment: I believe exec actually runs [`exec(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) and so only works in a new session, and runs the exec:ed process instead of a shell.

Comment: @slhck I'm having a hell of a time formatting this to be able to execute with `osascript -e` in the shell. Any advice?

Comment: @slhck nvm, found this little gem with EOD usage:http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103621/run-applescript-from-bash-script

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. `The variable terminal is not defined`

Answer (score 5):

If anyone in 2020 looking for answer to this, find below:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
    tell current session of newWindow
        write text "cd ~/Desktop; clear; pwd"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I have try this script, and it works for me. Reference: https://iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html

```
tell application "iTerm2"
  tell current window
    set newTab to (create tab with default profile)
    tell current session of newTab
      write text "cd ~/Documents; pwd"
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not on a Mac right now, so it might not work 100% (adapted [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/283418/how-can-i-make-terminal-vim-my-default-editor-application-in-mac-os-x/283422#283422)).

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set t to (make new terminal)
    tell t
        tell (make new session at the end of sessions)
            exec command "cd Downloads"
            exec command "clear"
            exec command "pwd"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

You can probably concatenate the commands to

```
cd Downloads ; clear ; pwd
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. `The variable terminal is not defined`