# Open multiple tabs in iTerm2 with a specific directories

Tags: macos, bash, iterm2

I would like to know if this is possible.

I want to set up some script or command that will open 5 tabs and each tab that will open will have their own directory specified

All in the same window

```
tab 1: open ~/folderA1
tab 2: open ~/folderA2
tab 3: open ~/folderA3
tab 4: open ~/folderA4
tab 5: open ~/folderA5
```

This is on iTerm2 in Mac OS X.

I know I can do something like CMD+T and then open each of them using `cd ~/folderA1` and so on, but if there is a command that I can set up or a script that after executing they will do that all at once I would love to know if there is a way to do so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** Newer iTerm requires you to change the syntax, so this would look like:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current window
        create tab with default profile
    end tell
    tell current tab of current window
        set _new_session to last item of sessions
    end tell
    tell _new_session
        select
        write text "cd \"$dir\""
    end tell
end tell
```

See also [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435951/how-to-write-text-to-a-iterm2-session-in-applescript).

---

For older iTerm versions:

Taking the script [from my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/299525/48078), you can do something like this:

```
launch () {
for dir in ~/folderA{1..5}; do
/usr/bin/osascript <<-EOF
tell application "iTerm"
    make new terminal
    tell the current terminal
        activate current session
        launch session "Default Session"
        tell the last session
            write text "cd \"$dir\""
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
EOF
done
}
```

To explain what's going on:

- We create a shell function named `launch`, so you can put this in your `~/.bash_profile` or wherever you want to have it executed at startup.
- We loop over the result of the Bash brace expansion `~/folderA{1..5}`, which gives you `~/folderA1` through `~/folderA5`.
- We call the iTerm2 AppleScript library through `osascript` to create a new tab, activate it, launch the default session, and `cd` to the specified directory.

Answer (score 8):

[itermocil](https://github.com/TomAnthony/itermocil) can handle this.

With the following in a file called `~/.itermocil/foo.yml`, the command `itermocil foo` would open 5 tabs in the specified folders.  (This is a really simple layout though - itermocil can do much more than this.)

```
windows:
  - name: '1'
    root: ~/folderA1
    layout: even-horizontal
    panes:
      - focus: true
  - name: '2'
    root: ~/folderA2
    layout: even-horizontal
    panes:
      - focus: true
  - name: '3'
    root: ~/folderA3
    layout: even-horizontal
    panes:
      - focus: true
  - name: '4'
    root: ~/folderA4
    layout: even-horizontal
    panes:
      - focus: true
  - name: '5'
    root: ~/folderA5
    layout: even-horizontal
    panes:
      - focus: true
```

Comment: itermocil doesn't seem to be supported any more and is broken on Mac OS 12.3. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't, I'm afraid. I don't really work this way any more, and tend to just manage my tabs and panes by hand. ‍♂️

Comment: I just tried this in my Mac Ventura (13.x) and it worked beautifully. Thank you for suggesting this